# How to print frequency of characters in a string?

Tags: c

Suppose the input is

> tree

The following code is showing an output of `t1r1e2e2`. How can I avoid printing `e2` twice?

```
int main() 
{
    char a[20];
    int count, j, i, k; //abcd
    gets(a);
    int p = strlen(a);

    for (j = 0; j < p; j++) {
        count = 0;
        for (k = 0; k < p; k++) {
            if (a[j] == a[k])
                break;
        }
        for (i = 0; i < p; i++) {
            if (a[j] == a[i]) {
                count++;
            }
        }
        printf("%c%d", a[j], count);
    }
}
```

Comment: Store the processed letters somewhere and then check against that. If the letter's been checked, do not loop again, etc. A hash table is easy to manufacture in this simple case, since ASCII letters are sequential in value.

Answer (score 0):

there are some problems in your code

- do not use *gets*, it is deprecated and if you enter a too long input you write out of the receiving string with an undefined behavior
- your loop with *k* is useless
- you use *int* but the right type is `size_t` because *int* may not be large enough

One way to do is to modify the string, supposing you do not want to count the newlines, and also changing the way to print the result to be more readable  :

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() 
{
  char a[20];

  if (fgets(a, sizeof(a), stdin) != NULL) {
    for (size_t j = 0; a[j] != 0; ++j) {
      char c = a[j];

      if (c != '\n') {
        size_t count = 1;

        for (size_t i = j + 1; a[i] != 0; i++) {
          if (a[j] == a[i]) {
            count += 1;
            a[i] = '\n'; /* to not count it again */
          }
        }

        printf("%c : %zu\n", a[j], count);
      }
    }
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Compilation and executions :

```
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ g++ -pedantic -Wall -Wextra c.c
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ ./a.out
tree
t : 1
r : 1
e : 2
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ ./a.outpi@
output input
o : 1
u : 3
t : 3
p : 2
  : 1
i : 1
n : 1
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $
```

If you want to manage all the characters including the newline you can memorize the initial length of the string for the loops and use the character 0 to mark the already count characters. Of course if you need to not modify the original string just work on a copy of it, or use an additional array containing the count of the characters (the index is the code of the character, warning if characters are signed), or check if the current character is present in the previous ones

Comment: IMO `main` function answers are for the 19k user a bit childish. You shoul show beginers that C is called the procedural language for the reason (but not because it has **function** `main`)

Comment: @P__J__ if I well understand you looking at your answer you blame me for making a simple answer instead of proposing something complicated for nothing (without speaking about the introductions of problems) ? We do not have the same point of view ... ;-)

Answer (score -1):

Here is another. You can process as many data as you wish just caliing the process function. init function zeroes the counters. It prints also not printable chars hex numbers `'\x0a'` for example

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>

static unsigned freqtable[256];

void init(void)
{
    memset(freqtable, 0, sizeof(freqtable));
}

unsigned *process(const unsigned char *buff, size_t size)
{
    while(size--)
    {
        freqtable[*buff++]++;
    }
    return freqtable;
}

void print(void)
{
    for(unsigned i = 0; i < 256; i++)
    {
        if(freqtable[i])
        {
            if(ispunct(i) || isalnum(i))
            {
                printf("%c%u", i, freqtable[i]);
            }
            else
            {
                printf("'\\x%02x%u", i, freqtable[i]);
            }
        }
    }
    printf("\n");
}

#define T1 "tree"

#define T2 "\r\nHello world \r\n\r\n"

int main()
{
    init();
    process(T1, strlen(T1));
    print();
    process(T2, strlen(T2));
    print();
    init();
    process(T2, strlen(T2));
    print();    

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: what problems my fliend

Comment: first the ones signaled by the compiler using the right options (using gcc there are 9 doing `gcc -pedantic -Wall -Wextra`) more the suppositions you do about _int_, _char_ etc

Comment: @bruno there was one of the size_t, edited some minuts ago. BTW it did not matter and I assume as revenge nitpick comment

Comment: no, this is not a revenge comment (that has no sense and I value more of that ... i hope ^^). Did you compile with options to get more warnings ? Out of the `size_t / int` problem you suppose an _unsigned char_ is between 0 and 255
. You also use _ispunct/isalnum_ on an _unsigned int_ while these functions request _int_ (and _isprint_ was a better choice). And why that ugly global var. To reuse your remark on my answer are you sure you help beginners to learn C well with that ? ( 
I am really surprised, usually your answers are not of this ilk ;-) )

Comment: the problem signed unsigned in this case can arise when unsigned will not fir into the signed. As I pass only unsigned char values it will never happen. This is false nitpick one written without deeper understanding of the issue. Global variable - it does not matter it it declared static in the function call. Both have the same static storage anyway.